Hirsch tangent bundle definition
I am new to differential topology, and I attempt to study it using Hirsch book "Differential Topology".
In the first chapter, after introducing the definition of manifold, he talks about tangent vectors and tangent bundles.
Given an n-dimensional manifold $M$, a tangent vector to $M$ is an equivalence class $[x,i,a]$ of triples
\begin{equation}
(x,i,a) \in M \times \Lambda \times R^n
\end{equation}
where $\Lambda$ is the atlas index set $\Phi = \{\phi_i,U_i\}_{i \in \Lambda}$. Equivalence relation is defined via $(x,i,a) ~ (x,j,b)$ iff
\begin{equation}
D \phi_j \phi_i^{-1}(\phi_i(x))a = b
\end{equation}
That is, the derivative of the coordinate change send vector $a$ to $b$.
The set of all tangent vectors is $TM$.
Note that every open set $U \subset M$ is also an n-dimensional manifold. First he defines $TU$ in the similar fashion using a derivative atlas $(\Phi | U)$.
Now the author claims that for every chart $(\phi_i,U_i)$ there is a well-defined bijective map
\begin{equation}
T\phi_i : TU_i \rightarrow \phi_i(U_i) \times R^n
\end{equation}
via $[x,i,a] \rightarrow (\phi_i(x),a)$.
I do not see how this map is well-defined. Which "element" of the equivalence class does it spit out? I have been trying to apply this definition to $S^2$ and reconcile it with Hairy Ball Theorem for example, and I feel this is where I am stuck.
